# How to debug angular when bower_components is two levels up

Tags: angularjs, yeoman-generator-angular

I moved my bower_components two levels up to get it out of my project, out of the way of source control because it's a build artifact, it's not my source code and it's not part of the build output (my build output concats all the vendor js into vendor.js, one file).

So I can build find and it creates my dist folder fine; I got that working.

But now when I try to serve in order to debug on my local machine, index.html correctly points to all the ../../artifacts/bower_components scripts and it can't find them when it runs in the web server. I guess because they are above the web root.

[image]

How can I get the web server to find them?

Comment: You should just ignore / remove the output files from source control, no need to change your directory structure.

Comment: @BrianGlaz, thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, we have a strange toolset that does not allow me to do that.

Comment: I don't know what you used for blurring text but it seems not very efficient:)

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos, so, don't use that to blur out my bitcoin private key in that forum, is what you're saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I moved my bower_components two levels up to get it out of my project, out of the way of source control because it's a build artifact

Moving *bower_components* one level up so as it is out of your *app* files is logical. But two levels up so that it is out of source control is not. This case is better handled by adding an exception to the ignore file *.(git|svn|...)ignore*

Anyway, depending on the server you use, you should be able to configure a route, so that the server serves also whats in the *bower_components* folder. Here is an example with `browsersync`:

```
server: {
    baseDir: "app",
    routes: {
        "/bower_components": "bower_components"
    }
}
```

The server serves what's inside `app` folder, and also maps the content of the *bower_components* folder to the route `/bower_components`.

Links in **index.html** look therefore like that:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/..."></script>
```

...even though *bower_components* is at a different level from `index.html`.

Comment: The wiredep build task will keep setting the urls to be '../../artifacts/bower_comonents/...'. I'm trying to research how to do this in my server. The idea sounds promising.

Comment: Hm, I don't have a big experience with wiredep, but it seems in your case the `ignorePath` property could be useful. It strips out a pattern of the injected file path.